ANOVA alternatives
Imagine the follwing study:

Objective: Test if a treatment enhances cognitive function.
Groups: 29 subjects in intervention group, 20 in control group.
Test: Answer as many questions as possible in 3 minutes, test done pre and post-treatment.
Metric: Proportion of correctly answered questions.

Assumptions:

Equal difficulty for each question (whatever that might mean).
Each subject answers a different total of questions.
Subjects may answer a different total of questions in pre and
post-test.
Large total of answered questions per subject.
Proportions of correct answers range from 0.7 to 1.0.
Distribution of proportions and residuals is NOT normal (mostly skewed to the right, see QQ plots and histograms below).

My concerns:
Traditional ANOVA isn't suitable due to non-normal distribution of residuals.
For me also the variation in total answered questions per subject adds complexity.
Question:
What statistical procedure should I use to determine if the intervention significantly improved the mean proportion of correctly answered questions?
Any ideas or directions would be greatly appreciated!
EDIT:
Here are the QQ plots of the residuals showing non-normality:

Distribution of proportions of correctly answered questions:


Why would the subjects answer a different set of questions per person? Wouldn't that make it very difficult to compare the tests against each other?

They are the same questions. Just some some subjects are faster at answering, thus answering more questions in the time limit. I know IT seems Strange but don't want to go into too much detail as i think it would make it more confusing.

The starting point is that your outcome reduces to a proportion between 0 and 1. That makes the idea that you expect normal distributions conditional on predictors to be implausible at the outset, even roughly. You have partly answered your own question by noting that ANOVA is problematic. What is on the face of it more appropriate would be a generalized linear model for the proportion of correct outcomes with (number of correct answers, number of answers) as a paired outcome. Binomial regression is an often used term. If presented with the data I would start with a logit link.

You're not using Stata but regardless https://www.stata.com/manuals/rbinreg.pdf gives the flavour and some references and you should be able to find similar functionality in your own favourite software. If not, you need new favourite software.

@NickCox thanks for the direction. My knowledge about GLMs is rather limited. It would be of great help if you could be more specific, e.g. show me how the model is mathematically formulated. I could look into resources to read more about it then.

Sorry, no. I've already given you a reference that in turn has references!
